# ASP.NET custom server control not retaining values after post back

Tags: asp.net

I have a custom server control (composite control having dynamically created dropdown boxes and textboxes). I have enabled AJAX in order to avoid page reload.The server control is used inside the ASP.NET webcontrol having few buttons which controls the visibility of the server control. Now I enter values in the dropdown box and texboxes and click on any other button. After this postback the last entered values are gone! The control is not remembering the values. Can anyone help me? How can I retain the values after post back?

Comment: Do you dynamically add the control during Page_Load?  Or is it declared in the aspx markup already?

Comment: Did work ok with out ajax ? if yes then see what javascript error you get on your page after the post back.

Comment: I have created the custom server control in asp.net.which will dynamiclly create the dropdown boxes and textboxes in the control.Im not using asp.net markup to create the controls.<%@ Register Assembly="abc" Namespace="abc"
    TagPrefix="cc1" %> cc1 is the server control and em using it inside the webcontrol.It is not working without ajax also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure that the controls are given the exact same ID after each postback.  Also you might want to try initialising your dynamic controls (DropDownList and TextBox) during Page_Init if possible.

Comment: Also, as @Aristos said, you need to create them on each postback!

Comment: @SirCrispalot you are the man. I was about to start down a really bad path if I couldn't figure this out.  I was populating ids with generated guids.

Comment: Regarding the Page_Init you mention - controls created on a CompositeControl suppose to be initialized from CreateChildControls method.

Answer (score 3):

If your custom server control is create dynamically all the controls, then you need to recreate them on every post, and **you need to create them before the Page_Load()**, or else the asp.net cant know them to filled with the post data.

To solve this, if you can not create them before the Page_Load(), then you can fill them by your self with the posted data by using the `Request.Form[YourCustomControl.UniqueID]` for all controls.

Answer (score 3):

You need to re-create on each postback, see [This article](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Dynamically_Created_Controls_in_ASPNET.aspx)

Comment: But i need to create the controls in createchildcontrols() method.re creating the same controls once again before page load will not help it. everytime postback happens will result in Page.Request.Form[ID] to be null.