# Get value of control after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, code-behind

I have a dynamic control in a page. It was added to this page by codebehind.

```
FileUpload fu = new FileUpload();
fu.ID = "fu";
fu.EnableViewState = true;
list.Add(fu);

Button btnFu = new Button();
btnFu.Text = "Upload";
btnFu.ID = "btnFu";
list.Add(btnFu);
```

After using postBack, I can't get the value from this fileUpload.

```
if (!IsPostBack) {

}
else {
      string str_btn = null;
      if (Request.Form.Keys[Request.Form.Keys.Count - 1] != null)
                    str_btn = Request.Form.Keys[Request.Form.Keys.Count - 1].ToString();
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str_btn)) 
                    handleClick(str_btn);

}
```

Anybody has a solution to resolve this?

Comment: Where do you add those controls?

Comment: I added it by codebehind.Adding it in child page.

Comment: Do you create them in Page_Load? Do you create them upon a form submission with a PostBack? Where and when exactly?

Comment: May you access my machine.I will show it more in detail.yes? use teamviewer?

Comment: I'm sorry but I have neither tiemviewer installed on my machine nor I have time for that. You should hire an advisor.

Comment: I created it isn't in Page_Load.It was created at another side when I press button.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26214/discussion-between-binh-tieu-and-mostruash)

Comment: i think the answers are here and this is a duplicate
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552243/asp-net-custom-server-control-not-retaining-values-after-post-back

Answer (score 0):

I would try searching for the control using Page.FindControl("fu").  There are some interesting options in the answers to this question covering issues like looking for controls when using masterpages and user controls.

[ASP.Net FindControl is not working - How come?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799655/asp-net-findcontrol-is-not-working-how-come)

Comment: Oh,yes,That's it.I used masterpage and ContentPlaceHolder,brother.

Comment: I tried but it didn't work.May we make a conversation,brother

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the list you have added the controls to is a content container so you must first get a reference to it then call the `FindControl("btnFu")` method.

```
// var list = yourListControl
Button btnFu = list.FindControl("btnFu") as Button;
if(btnFu != null)
{
    // Operate on the button
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to recreate your dynamically created controls on a post back, I believe.

```
public class YourPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
      protected bool AreControlsCreated {
      {
          get{return (bool)ViewState["AreControlsCreated"];}
          set{ViewState["AreControlsCreated"] = value;}
      }

      private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
      {
          if(!IsPostBack)
          {
              AreControlsCreated = false;
          }
          else if(AreControlsCreated)
          {
              CreateYourControls();
          }
      }

      private void CreateYourControls()
      {
        ...
        FileUpload fu = new FileUpload();
        fu.ID = "fu";
        fu.EnableViewState = true;
        list.Add(fu);

        Button btnFu = new Button();
        btnFu.Text = "Upload";
        btnFu.ID = "btnFu";
        list.Add(btnFu);

        AreControlsCreated = true;
      }

      protected void YourButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          createYourControls();
      }
}
```

Comment: Hi brother,Thanks for your reply.I see your idea.I believe that it will work fine if we lost control.But in my case,It still show control,But I can't get value from this control.So that,My problem is that can't get value from FileUpload

Comment: How do you try to get the value? Show me your code. You are doing many things wrong including creating controls in behind code. You can put them in the markup as not-visible and make them visible upon a click of a button. Read some books/articles/blogs on best practices.